# Adding sound in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

the sound is not playing for the second touch it only plays for the first touch the sound is only 0.02 duration and its in mp3 it plays only for first touch but i have to make it for each click and it should feel like accelarator

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    public class Player : MonoBehaviour 
    {
        // The force which is added when the player jumps
        // This can be changed in the Inspector window
    public Vector2 jumpForce = new Vector2(0, 300);
    public AudioClip imp;
        public AudioSource clk;
        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update ()
        {
            // Jump
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {

                GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.zero; 
                GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(jumpForce);
                clk.PlayOneShot (imp, 0.7f);

            }
            Vector2 screenPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
            if (screenPosition.y > Screen.height || screenPosition.y < 0)
            {
                Die();
            }
        }

        // Die by collision
        void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
        {
            Die();
        }


        void Die()
        {

            Application.LoadLevel(0);

        }
    }
```

Comment: any errors? What does your debugging say? I see no debugging code in your class

Comment: thier was no errors

Comment: it plays automaticaly if i untick play on awake it not even sounds

Comment: @Martin it not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sound is not playing for the second touch because Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) will only detect one touch. You loop through the `Touches` then play sound if one is pressed. Break the loop after the first touch is detected since you only one to play one sound when there is a touch on the screen.

```
void Update()
{
    int touches = Input.touchCount;
    Debug.Log(touches);

    for (int i = 0; i < touches; i++)
    {
        if (touches > 0 && Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            clk.PlayOneShot(imp, 0.7f);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {

        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.zero;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(jumpForce);
    }
    Vector2 screenPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
    if (screenPosition.y > Screen.height || screenPosition.y < 0)
    {
        Die();
    }
}
```

Comment: it dont even play the sound

Comment: @GBGolden Tested it and it works. That code will only work on mobile devices. When you said  second touch, you are doing this on a mobile device ,right?

Comment: @GBGolden Its a mobile code. there is only one touch on pc

Comment: the same problem it only works for the first time and it seems that it plays automaticaly

Comment: have you checked it?

Comment: @GBGolden **the same problem it only works for the first time and it seems that it plays automaticaly** please explain what is not working exactly....What do you expect to have? I don't know what you really want

Comment: i want to play it  loops for each touch i have to play the sound as u can see in the images it a tappy plane game so for each touch the plane sound has to play

Comment: @GBGolden I still don't understand. You want to play different sound for each touch? If so, where are the sounds?

Comment: no its not it has to play in loops the sounds are same propeller sound but for each touch i have to replay the sound the sound is mp3 file and it has added to music folder in assets and imported  public AudioClip imp;
 public AudioSource clk;

Comment: are u still working on my code? a simple help is aprreciated